# Problema ao rodar Jplayer quando há mais de um item

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma listagem de 3 players de áudio por página, fiz todas com Jplayer.

O que está acontecendo, é que quando eu executo o primeiro item, ele executa todos juntos.

Ou seja, se eu clicar no 1º item, ele executa os 3 que se encontram na mesma página.

Código http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/yNxAL/

Comment: Usou a mesma classe para nomear todos?

Comment: Na verdade, percebi que usei o mesmo ID, dentro de um laço de repetição. Só que não sei como resolver isso =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/), particularmente pelas demonstrações presentes no site para versões de múltiplas instâncias na mesma página, todas elas tem que ser instanciadas de forma independente.

O problema está que com múltiplas instâncias temos que passar o parâmetro `cssSelectorAncestor` ao jPlayer para ele trabalhar cada *player* de forma independente.

## Exemplo

[Ver demonstração no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/4r4uL/)

```
/* Por cada classe "jp-jplayer" vamos
 * instanciar um jPlayer
 */
$(".jp-jplayer").each(function() {

  var $this      = $(this),                         // colocar referência ao player em cache
      myAncestor = "#" + $this.next().attr("id");   // recolher o ID do "cssSelectorAncestor"

  $this.jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: "Bubble",
            m4a: "http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
            oga: "http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "m4a, oga",
    cssSelectorAncestor: myAncestor,    // passar a referência de ID recolhida
    wmode: "window",
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true,
    remainingDuration: true,
    toggleDuration: true
  });
});
```

---

[Este link para uma das páginas de demonstração do jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-03-video/) evidência, se observarmos o código fonte, que é tudo instanciado com referencia a identificadores únicos.

No exemplo que apresento em cima, fazemos uso de um trecho de código para instanciar vários *players* que contenham a classe de CSS `jp-player`.

Comment: Show de bola, o que acontece é que essa classe `jquery_jplayer_1` ela está no laço de repetição, e ele não muda o nome, por isso está repetindo, o que acontece é que não sei como mudar isso. Fiz o teste que você gerou e continua repetindo.

Comment: @FelipeStoker presumo que estejas a gerar o HTML com alguma linguagem tipo PHP, certo? Se sim, o ID para cada jPlayer pode ser gerado dinamicamente mediante cada passagem do ciclo, mas sem saber a linguagem que estás a usar é difícil ;)

Comment: Exatamente, estou utilizando PHP. =D

Comment: Tudo isso daqui repete http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/fC3E9/

Comment: @FelipeStoker Em PHP, podes gerir o teu ciclo [conforme este exemplo](http://ideone.com/ELPuS9). Assim obténs IDs diferentes para cada player.

Comment: atualizei minha pergunta inicial, encontrei uma solução. Obrigado. =D

Comment: @FelipeStoker Não coloques a solução na pergunta, podes responder à tua pergunta com a tua solução, poderá ajudar futuros visitantes com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido, encontrei a **solução** aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784917/how-to-implement-multi-instance-jplayers